# Get list of recent projects when opening Visual Studio in Windows 8 and 2012

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-server-2012

On Windows 7 I open Visual Studio by hitting Start, choosing VS, and then choosing the solution I want from a list of recent solutions.

On the variants of Windows with no start button I cannot do it this way.  I hit start, type "Vis..." and get VS showing up on the search bar.  But I do not see any way to get a list of recent projects.

This is annoying because it means this is a two step process rather than one click.  Does anyone know how to open Visual Studio and a recent project with one click?

Windows 7 shows a list of recent solutions:

[image]

Windows 8 with no list of recent files:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you pin visual studio to your taskbar, and do a right click on it, you will find your recent projects list.
[image]

Comment: Agree with user3454923. Only thing you need to do is pin it to the task bar once. I use the same from Windows 8.1.